# Gaussian space generated by Gaussian process

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have a somewhat silly question after reading the following definition in *Brownian motion, martingales and stochastic calculus* by Jean-François Le Gall

> **Proposition 1.7** If $(X_t)_{t\in T}$ is a Gaussian process, the closed linear subspace of
> $L^2$ spanned by the variables $X_t, t\in T$, is a Gaussian space, which is called the
> Gaussian space generated by the process $X$.

My question is: how do we prove that this space is closed? If I denote this space by $G$, and I take a sequence $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $G$ that converges to some $Y\in L^2$, I can show that $Y$ is a centered Gaussian. But how do I show that $Y$ is a linear combination of the $(X_t)_{t\in T}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$ is the [closed linear span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span#Closed_linear_span_(functional_analysis)) of $(X_t)$, i.e., the elements of $G$ need not belong to the linear span of $(X_t)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I wondered whether it was included in the definition.

Comment: $G$ is the smallest closed linear subspace of $L^2$ containing $(X_t)$.